# azure data factory - How To Trim Whitespace for CopyData

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I'm using the CopyData component to Extract-Load data from pipe-delimited files in to Azure SQL DW.

Generally this is working fine, but it seems the default behavior is to not trim whitespace on **string** columns in the delimited file. So the sink to the Azure SQL DW table can't handle the column varchar width.

---

### Example

```
"Value Name Example                                      "
```

This won't work with a **VARCHAR(20)** table column target. Truncation error occurs.

---

What is the normal practice for this? Is it considered "Transform", and so we have to resort to SSIS or other compute?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a JSON trim() expression notwithstanding, expressions don't seem to work in the dataset mapping table...(hopefully) yet.

If you have a SQL Server instance available, you can pass the data set as a table value to a Stored Procedure that trims the fields and performs any other necessary modifications.